# How to initialise a std::map once so that it can be used by all objects of a class?

Tags: c++, static-members, stdmap

I have an enum StackIndex defined as follows:

```
typedef enum 
{
    DECK,
    HAND,
    CASCADE1,
    ...
    NO_SUCH_STACK
} StackIndex;
```

I have created a class called `MoveSequence`, which is a wrapper for a `std::deque` of a bunch of tuples of the form `<StackIndex, StackIndex>`.

```
class MoveSequence
{
    public:
        void AddMove( const tpl_move & move ){ _m_deque.push_back( move ); }
        void Print();
    protected:
    deque<tpl_move> _m_deque;
};
```

I thought I could create a static `std::map` member of the `MoveSequence` class, which would translate a `StackIndex` to a `std::string`, for use by the `Print()` function. But when I tried, I got the error:

```
"error C2864: 'MoveSequence::m' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class"
```

If its not possible to created a std::map as a static member, is there another way to create a std::map that translates a `StackIndex` to a `std::string` that can be used to print out `MoveSequence` objects?

thanks

Beeband.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a std::map a static member of the class.  What you can't do is initiliaze it within the class definition.  Note that this is what the error is telling you:

> error C2864: 'MoveSequence::m' : only static const integral data members can be ***initialized*** within a class

So, you want to have this in the header:

```
class MoveSequence
{
    static std::map<StackIndex, std::string> _m_whatever;
};
```

And then in a source (.cpp) file you want this:

```
std::map<StackIndex, std::string> MoveSequence::_m_whatever( ..constructor args.. );
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to move the initialization into a source file:

```
// header
struct foo
{
    typedef std::map<unsigned, std::string> the_map;
    static const the_map m;
};

// source
const foo::the_map foo::m(...);
```

With however you want to initialize it. C++0x removes this restriction.

Keep in mind [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) makes this quite easy:

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
const foo::the_map foo::m = boost::assign::map_list_of(1, "a")(2, "b");
```

Comment: I dunno, just whatever he had in his header (i.e. I'm guessing). I'll change it.

Comment: Thanks GMan! I tried the boost assign thing in the class, that's what gave me the error.

Comment: Can't find about static initializers in C++0x, if it is static, which translation unit has the storage? I've seen it for non-static members in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2628.html

Comment: I thought maybe `static const` had a special case, but I can't find it either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want a std::map (although all of the other answers here are good ones as to how to do that). It sounds like you just want a static C array of strings, where the index is the enum value.

```
const char* const stacknames[] = 
{
    "deck",
    "hand",
    "cascade1"
};
```

Then stacknames[DECK] is "deck", etc.

Comment: Brilliant. I really do love this site for all the new ideas. However, is there a big difference in speed between a std::map and an array of strings?

Comment: Yes, an array of strings will be much faster.

Comment: If StackIndex is consecutive integral values (or at least does not have too many large holes in it), an array is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you need to create a static instance of the map in a C++ source file. When it comes to initialising it, I suggest creating a static function in MoveSequence:

```
class MoveSequence {

   static void InitMap() {
      if ( m_map.size() == 0 ) {
           m_map.insert( std::make_pair( DECK, "deck" ) );
            m_map.insert( std::make_pair( HAND, "hand" ) );
      }
   }
   ...
};
```

You can then call this from MoveSequence's constructor.

Oh, and BTW there is no need for the typedef on the enum:

```
enum StackIndex {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks Neil. I suppose with the boost::assign thing, I was trying to get away with typing less, as I have about 24 `StackIndex`s in my enum :).

Comment: Neil, why not `if ( !m_map.empty() )`?